# Why does OAuth 2.0 spec suggest using HTTP GET for delivering auth code to client?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, get, authorization, http-redirect

In the OAuth 2.0 Spec, the authors suggest¹ to realize the [Authorization Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2) using a HTTP `302` redirect to the previously provided `redirect_uri` - most likely pointing to the backend server (confidential client). This will make the user's (resource owner) browser (user agent) perform a GET request to that URI. The client will then use the auth code included in this request to obtain an access code from the authorization server and answer this request in some appropriate way.

This operation however - *triggered by the GET-request* - is not [idempotent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Idempotent) without significat extra measures implemented in the client and *certainly* not [safe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Safe/HTTP). Thus it contradicts the [requirements of HTTP-GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET).

Is this a legitimate concern? How should I take this into account when implementing the redirection endpoint of my own OAuth 2.0 client?

---

¹: Precisely, the exact method used to redirect is an implementation detail, but all the examples use `302` (see [section 1.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.7) of the spec).

Comment: This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) explained,  recommended to set the 302 code only as a response for GET or HEAD methods.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example authorization response, as an HTTP GET, and it is idempotent. Eg you could receive the response, then reload the browser URL multiple times, before using the authorization code.

```
GET https://www.example.com?code=xxx&state=yyy
```

What is not idempotent is the next request in the OAuth workflow, to POST an authorization code grant message, to exchange the code for tokens.

```
POST http://login.example.com/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=myclient
&client_secret=mysecrrt
&code=xxx
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback
```

After processing the GET request, it is pretty standard to navigate to a post login location, rather than leave the `code=xxx&state=yyy` query parameters showing in the browser (where a user could cause problems by reloading the page). For example, [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L130) does so using the browser history API:

```js
history.replaceState({}, document.title, '/');
```

**RESPONSE MODE**

It is common these days to use OIDC and OAuth together. The [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) specs define a `response_mode` parameter, whose default value is `query`. This enables you to receive the authorization response differently if you prefer:

- [response_mode=form_post](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html)
- [response_mode=jwt](https://openid.net/specs/openid-financial-api-jarm-ID1.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I assume you are talking about a specifc OAuth authorization servcer implentation. I cannot find anything about a `response_mode` in the original RFC. Moreover I do not see, what exactly you refer to as *this*, being "an idempotent HTTP request".

Comment: Ah - it is OpenID Connect. If you are not using that and OAuth together, ignore the second part of my answer. I also updated my answer with example messages. Nothing here is vendor specific - it is all standards based.

Comment: Thanks, I can follow your answer much better now. However, it still wonder about my key-question: Since the `GET https://www.example.com?code=xxx&state=yyy`-request would usually cause the OAuth-Client (at `www.example.com`) to perform the Access Token Request (to `POST http://login.example.com/oauth/token`), doesn't that make the `GET` (not *necessarily* idempotent, but certainly) unsafe?

Comment: And even if the `GET`-request did *not* immediatey trigger the Access Token Request internally, it still sends *some* information to process or persist *to* the server at `www.example.com` (specifically the `code`), which makes this request non-readonly and thereby non-safe.

Comment: I think perhaps what you are concerned about is the user reloading the page and trying to reuse the code, resulting in an error. If so, I get your point, but the OAuth messages are not wrong in HTTP / REST terms. It is just that the app needs to take a redirect action, which is always needed if a one-time token is received in a URL. See the comment I added to my answer.

Comment: Everything you say makes sense to me and I frankly appreciate your patience but unfortunately I still don't see this as an satisfying answer to my actual question: The `GET` request from the user agent to the OAuth client includes a `code` that - as an immediate effect of _only_ this `GET`-request - either must be *stored* or *processed* by the backend in *some* way. Doesn't this make this `GET` operation unsafe? I would be disconcerned to implement this backend-service as such, since it is after all _only_ a `GET`-service, which always dictates "no modification of server state in any way".

Comment: Thanks for pursuing additional clarity on this, @Reizo. After reading the answer from Gary Archer, the same question remains—"If we assume the OAuth callback handler is implemented correctly, where it redeems the one-time OAuth code, doesn't that make the GET request _not_ idempotent?"

Comment: As an example of a canonical non-idempotent, non-safe operation, let's consider an endpoint which creates a new object per request. How would "reload the browser URL multiple times, before [triggering the operation]" be possible here? (Or does it not apply?) Assuming the endpoint functions as designed, any incoming request would lead to the non-idempotent operation being performed, no?

Comment: A GET that creates resources is not the same thing. The key difference is that OAuth uses established web patterns for nonces - values that can only be used once. Another example is a reset password link, which has to be a GET request.